# Converting $x = \sin \frac{t}{2}, y = \cos \frac{t}{2}$ to Cartesian form

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

How can we transform these parametric equations to Cartesian form?

$$x = \sin \frac{t}{2}, \quad y = \cos \frac{t}{2}, \quad -\pi \leq t \leq \pi.$$

Comment: What is the result of $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = r^2$. that was a hint?

Comment: Yes, it is constant 1, so the curve is contained on the unitary circle. Try to determine the end points.

Comment: I understand Sigur, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $-\pi\leq t\leq \pi$ then $-\pi/2\leq t/2\leq \pi/2$. Also $x^2+y^2=1$.

Here is the animated curve for $0\leq t\leq \pi$. Try to imagine what happens for $t$ negative.[image: animated curve]

Answer (score 1):

$$x = \sin \frac{t}{2}, \quad y = \cos \frac{t}{2}, \quad -\pi \leq t \leq \pi.$$

$$x^2+y^2=(\sin \frac{t}{2})^2+(\cos \frac{t}{2})^2=1$$ so
$$x^2+y^2=1$$ is equation of some circle